# Reanimated useCode hook doesn't work as expected

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I'm using `react-native-reanimated` on my [react-native](/questions/tagged/react-native) app. I'm also using `react-native-redash`. I'm trying to make a modal with some gestures, so I have the following code:

```
const [ height, setHeight ] = useState(SNAP_TOP);
const [ velocityY, translationY, offset, state ] = useValues(0, 0, height, State.UNDETERMINED);

const gestureHandler = onGestureEvent({
  state,
  velocityY,
  translationY,
});

const springTranslation = withSpring({
  state,
  offset,
  velocity: velocityY,
  value: translationY,
  config: { damping: 15 },
  snapPoints: [ SNAP_BOTTOM, height - HEADER_HEIGHT, height ],
  onSnap: () => {
    state.setValue(State.UNDETERMINED)
  },
});

const translateY = interpolate(springTranslation, {
  extrapolate: Extrapolate.CLAMP,
  inputRange: [ SNAP_BOTTOM, height ],
  outputRange: [ SNAP_BOTTOM, height ],
});
```

So, this gestures works great, but on some specific moments I need to show or hide my modal, so I declare the following:

```
useCode(() => block([
  cond(
    eq(state, State.UNDETERMINED),
    [
      set(
        offset,
        timing({ clock, from: visible ? height : 0, to: visible ? 0 : height, duration: 400 })
      ),
    ],
  ),
]), [ visible ]);
```

And here is the issue, when `onSnap` function is executed from `redash` the `useCode` is executed again, and I really don't know why this is happening, because I'm using deps for `visible` prop, which  is a property coming from parent component used to show or hide the modal. I've having a lot of problems with `useCode` deps, because it does not work as I expected. Somebody can help me, o explain if `useCode` is working as good?

Comment: Maybe you are missing some dependencies! To me it looks like `state`, `offset` and `clock` should also be added.